# How can I set the media type to docker while building the image using kaniko

Tags: docker, containers, manifest, kaniko

I want my image to be build using media type docker in the manifest like `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`
but instead media type is being set as oci `application/vnd.oci.image.config.v1+json"` by default

I see kaniko by default builds the image using oci media type. Is there a way I can build and push the image in kaniko using docker media type

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer except that my image have the docker manifests, not OCI...

Answer (score 2):

This question is already 5 months old, but during investigation of an issue, I stumbled upon it and wanted to document my findings:

As per my testing, Kaniko (v1.15.0) produces manifests with different media types depending on the base image used for the build. That means, if your base image's manifest media type is `application/vnd.oci.image.config.v1+json`, the resulting image's manifest media type will be the same. This is also true for the `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` media type.

Unfortunately, I did not find any way to force the resulting image manifest's media type using kaniko. Podman seems to have a respective command line argument for the `build` subcommand: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-build.1.html#format